# How to get failed stage name during parallel run of stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I've a pipeline where multiple stages run in parallel but if any of the stages fails, I want to get its name to show failed stage. With following code, even if it fails in first stage ie `Checking Redmine access`, it always show last stage as failed i.e. `Checking Reviewers list`. This is because it runs in parallel and latest assigned value is picked up.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label {
            label "<machine-ip>"
            customWorkspace "workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckoutTest"
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Verify inputs') {

            parallel {
                stage('Checking Redmine access') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
                            echo "Redmine"
                            sh'''hello'''
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Checking SVN access') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
                            echo "SVN"
                        }
                    }

                }
                stage('Checking Reviewers list') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
                            echo "Reviewer"
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            script {
                echo "Failed stage is " + FAILED_STAGE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can get exactly failed stage of parallel running stages? or it will be also ok with me if parent stage name is returned as failed stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use a `post { failure {` block for each stage : see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label {
            label "<machine-ip>"
            customWorkspace "workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckoutTest"
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Verify inputs') {

            parallel {
                stage('Checking Redmine access') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            echo "Redmine"
                            sh'''hello'''
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        failure {
                            script {
                                echo "Failed stage is ${STAGE_NAME}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Checking SVN access') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
                            echo "SVN"
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        failure {
                            script {
                                echo "Failed stage is ${STAGE_NAME}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Checking Reviewers list') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
                            echo "Reviewer"
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        failure {
                            script {
                                echo "Failed stage is ${STAGE_NAME}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks man this worked! I had been using `post { failure {` after `stage` block and it was giving syntax error and it worked as you used inside `stage` but after `steps`. Also documentation does not have this clarity. Is this trial and error that helped you to come this point or some other doc/post?

Comment: Glad it could help. I suppose trial and error is always a good method when the documentation can't be found or lacks clarity :-)